# Append audio file to an existing one

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

My Android application records audio and stores it on the SD card and shows it in list format. I need to edit this audio; suppose I open recording, I need to start this recording again from ending and able to append audio in that recording.

Suppose my recording "My_Record#01" time is 04.06 sec and I want to add more audio in the recording then it must start from 04.07 and add some audio. In other words, you have made a recording in the morning, and if you want some other recording which make in the evening to be a continuation of the recording from morning, you don't need to record it separately. You can simply make the new recording to the end of the previously made recording

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SequenceInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html).

The `SequenceInputStream` class allows you to concatenate multiple `InputStreams`. A `SequenceInputStream` constructor uses either a pair of `InputStreams` or an `Enumeration` of `InputStreams` as its argument:

```
SequenceInputStream(InputStream first, InputStream second) // eg. Say for two files. 
SequenceInputStream(Enumeration streamEnum) // eg. Say multiple files.
```

Operationally, the class fulfills read requests from the first `InputStream` until it runs out and then switches over to the second one. In the case of an `Enumeration`, it will continue through all of the `InputStreams` until the end of the last one is reached.

If this thing does not work for you, then use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)

[Android-ffmpeg-tutorial](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial)